# Bun.js: Read a single line user input

Tags: javascript, stdin, readline, bun

[Bun.js](https://bun.sh/) has a [useful native API to read periodical user input](https://bun.sh/guides/process/stdin):

```js
const prompt = "Type something: ";
process.stdout.write(prompt);
for await (const line of console) {
  console.log(`You typed: ${line}`);
  process.stdout.write(prompt);
}
```

Is there a way to read user inputs, outside a loop?

---

I found this solution:

```js
const stdinIterator = process.stdin.iterator()

console.write('What is your name?\n> ')
const userName = (await stdinIterator.next()).value.toString().trimEnd()
console.log('Hello,', userName)

console.write(`What would you like, ${userName}?\n> `)
const answer = (await stdinIterator.next()).value.toString().trimEnd()
console.log('Do something with answer:', answer)
```

It works. But then the process is not terminated automatically (I need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> manually).

Comment: Just add a `break;` at the end of the loop.

Comment: Directly accessing the console iterator is broken. https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/7541